# Reuse Web Browser preference page

Tags: eclipse, browser, e4, eclipse-neon

I have an e4 application and I want to just pull in the eclipse->preferences -> General -> Web Browser preference page into my application.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, for a pure e4 application this preference page is not available (nor are any of the others that use `IWorkbenchPreferencePage`).

In addition the web browser code this preference page configures is also not available in an e4 application.

In general anything in most `org.eclipse.ui.xxxx` plugins is **not** available to a pure e4 application.